# parse.com A Cloud Job of few words

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I am trying to create a simple Cloud Job on parse.com but it doesn't behave as expected.

The job returns without error but in the process I am making a find query that seems to be thrown out to the void. There is no error, my console.log are visible before executing query.find() but after that nothing... The query seems to fail silently.

Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("maintenanceJob", function(request, status) {

    return performMaintenanceTasks().then(function() { 
       status.success("Parse Job done");
    }, function(errors) {
        status.error(tools.prettifyError(errors));
    });

});


function performMaintenanceTasks ()
{
    // If we have more than NB_MAX_ITEMS objects in Items, let's delete some
    var query = new Parse.Query(Items);
    return query.count({
      success: function(count) {
        if(count > NB_MAX_ITEMS) {
            return deleteOldItems(1); // 1 is used for test
        } 
        return Parse.Promise.as("Nothing to do.");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        return Parse.Promise.error(error);
      }
    });

}

function deleteOldItems(nbToDelete) {

    // (...)

    var query = new Parse.Query(Items);
    query.ascending("createdAt");
    query.limit(nbToDelete);
    query.include("rawData");

    console.log("I am visible in console, but NOTHING AFTER ME. query.find() seems to return immediately"); 

    return query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            // I never pass here
            var promise = Parse.Promise.as();

            _.each(results, function (item) {

                // For each item, extend the promise with a function to delete it.
                promise = promise.then(function () {

                    var rawData = item.get("rawData");

                    // If we have a rawData, delete it before Item
                    if (rawData && rawData.id) {

                        return rawData.destroy({
                            success: function (theObj) {
                                return item.destroy({
                                    success: function (anotherObj) {
                                        // I never pass here
                                        return Parse.Promise.as();
                                    },
                                    error: function (anotherObj, error) {
                                        // I never pass here
                                        return Parse.Promise.as();
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            error: function (theObj, error) {
                                // I never pass here
                                return Parse.Promise.as();
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        return item.destroy({
                            success: function (anotherObj) {
                                // I never pass here
                                return Parse.Promise.as();
                            },
                            error: function (anotherObj, error) {
                                // I never pass here
                                return Parse.Promise.as();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

            return promise;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // I never pass here
            return Parse.Promise.error(error);
        }
    }).then(function (nil) {
        // I never pass here
        return Parse.Promise.as("DELETEOLDITEMS: Job finished");
    }, function(error) {
        // I never pass here
        return Parse.Promise.error(error);
    });
}
```

(I have tested to replace every // I never pass here with console.log(), without any result)

I tried many different things but I believe this should work! Or at least return errors!

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Even weirder, if I modify performMaintenanceTasks to skip query.count():

```
function performMaintenanceTasks()
{
    return deleteOldItems(1);
}
```

the query.find() in deleteOldItems() is correctly executed this time!

What does that mean? Am I not allowed to nest queries on the same class?

Comment: You are mixing Promises and "old-style" callbacks with anonymous functions, I would suggest keeping it promises only.

Comment: I am using this kind of coding style in Cloud Code without issues but thanks for the suggestion. Still, I tried what you said just to be 100% sure; I get rid of the functions and put every promises in the Cloud.job(). Unfortunately that didn't change a thing. However, I am going to update my question as I have continued my experiments and might be able to better point where the issue is. Could be a bug in fact...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this pertains to you, but I know from my a personal experience that the Parse log can seem a little unintuitive. The Parse log only spits out 10 lines by default, so ensure you're specifying the log length every time you check.

```
parse log -n 1000
```

...is what I tend to do every time. This just makes debugging easier.

Comment: Yep, I was aware of that but thanks for sharing the info! 
In the end I removed the ```count()``` query from ```performMaintenanceTasks()``` and I never knew why ```deleteOldItems()``` wasn't performing correctly when nested in it.
I put it on the fact that doing a ```count()``` request is costly and my table was > 100K lines, parse wasn't handling that correctly...